# Problem with \cite{key}

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I'm having frustrating issues with my bibtex citation. In my .bib file, I have a citation like:

```
@article{Bonte2008,   
   author =       {M.H.A Bonte and AH van den Boogaard and J Huetink},
   title =        {An optimisation strategy for industrial metal forming processes.},   
   journal =     {Structural and Multidisciplinary Optimization},   
   year =         {2008},   
   volume =    {35},   
   pages =     {571-586},
}
```

Then, when I cite it in my tex file: `\cite{Bonte2008}`, I get the following (with `\bibliographystyle{spbasic}`)

> "as cited by [Bonte et al(2008)Bonte, van den Boogaard, and Hutink]."

That is, the Bonte et al(2008) is alright. However, it keeps adding the rest of the authors after it. Same thing, if I look at the references, i.e.

> [Bonte et al(2008)Bonte, van den Boogaard, and Hutink] Bonte M, van
>   den Boogaard A, Hutink J (2008) An opti- misation strategy for
>   industrial metal forming processes. Structural and Multidisciplinary
>   Optimization 35:571–586

Can someone please tell me why It's adding the names after the citation and how to remove them?

Comment: We need more information ... please post an example LaTeX code that can be used alongside the above `.bib` entry to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{natbib}` in your preamble?